# Magento 1.9 GET Order List via API URL

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento version: 1.9.4.1

Trying to come up with a SOAP api GET request v1 or v2 to bring all the orders list.
Have already read the documentation:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html

Have already created an apiuser and apikey from the System backend SOAP/XML-RPC with admin permissions.

Tried this with no result.
https://www.magentohost.com/api/soap/?wsdl?apiuser=xxx&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Im trying to come up with a working URL so i can then import the order list into a Google Sheet. 
Can't use Zapier or Integromat for this.

Comment: do you want to get order list via script ? ie PHP code using API.

Comment: Only vía directa url so i can importdata on Google Sheets or use API connector addon or using Google app script

Comment: I think with direct URL it is not possible(because to access API, you need first to create token and add token in request), you can put logic in script and manipulate (import) result wherever you want !

Comment: @Pawan any sample code for google app script?

Comment: i do not have any idea of google app script :( , can share PHP code and you need to convert it .

Comment: yes please do .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108547/discussion-between-sebas-and-pawan).

Comment: Please see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all order using below code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$url = 'http://127.0.0.1/1924sample/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient($url);


// get token
$session = $client->login('soapadmin', 'admin@123');
$result = $client->salesOrderList($session); 

var_dump ($result);
```

You need to change, username, password and HostURL

Hope above will help!